# How to compile amule 2.3.1?

Tags: 11.10

I was following [HowTo Compile In Ubuntu](http://wiki.amule.org/index.php/HowTo_Compile_In_Ubuntu) but run into error message like this:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/krasinski/Applications/amule/wx/build/wxGTK-2.8.12/utils/wxrc'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/krasinski/Applications/amule/wx/build/wxGTK-2.8.12/utils/wxrc'
make: *** [wxrc] Error 2
```

`

Comment: Did you make sure to do `../wxGTK-2.8.12/configure --with-gtk --without-libtiff --without-subdirs --enable-unicode --enable-optimise` first?

Comment: Yes, I did run these commands, and waited for a pretty long time.  Do you know what does "../" mean? Is "./" approximately equals to "sh"?

Comment: `..` Means the next folder up in the heirarchy. You're half way correct on the other. It actually means both "file file in this folder" (`.` is the same as the current folder). However, if the start of the command is `./somefile` and somefile is executable it is executed. I believe this is equivalent to `. somefile`. I think the shell explands `.` at the beginning of a line to mean the current shell (i.e /bin/bash), though if you're super-interested you could check the man page.

Comment: You probably didn't do the ./configure in the wxGTK* directory. Usually source comes with a hollow Makefile that gets make whole by ./config. So, you can't just run `make` off the bat - you have to ./configure first.

Comment: Thank for your help,I have added its source to my software list. What you said is pretty informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amule has an official .deb package in their forum for Ubuntu Oneiric (v. 2.3.1)

http://forum.amule.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=2a2047ac19efe9ecccdebedd70ea1938&topic=19378.0

Comment: Link is dead :(

Comment: That it is. It appears the whole amule.com is gone. I've looked but haven't been able to find another .deb package.